# make a category branch undeletable

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

I would make a category branch undeletable, my idea is to use an observer on the events `catalog_category_delete_before` and `catalog_category_delete_after`.
On `catalog_category_delete_before` the branch is cloned and stored into an instance variable.
On `catalog_category_delete_after` the branch is copied again.
I would know if there is a better way to achieve this result.
Example:

```
class EternalParquet_Category_Model_Observer {
private $cloned_category;

public function copy_category($observer = null) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $helper = Mage::helper('eternalParquet_macrocategoria');
    $category = $event->getCategory();
    $this->cloned_category = clone $category;
    //copy branch...
}

public function insert_category($observer = null) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $category = $this->cloned_category;

    /* insert branch... */  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid any category deletion, you could use the `catalog_category_delete_before` event and throw an exception in the observer :

```
public function stopDeletion($observer){
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Category deletion is not allowed.'))
}
```

If you need to do this only for specific category (for example the one with an attribute `is_branch` set to true), you can check the category in the observer :

```
public function stopDeletion($observer){
    $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
    if($category->getIsBranch()){
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Branch Category deletion is not allowed.'))
    }    
}
```